# casting elements of uint8 vector to stringstream

Tags: c++, vector, stringstream, uint8t

I'm havig some trouble figuring out how to conver my uint8 vector to stringstream.

On input im getting vector of uint8, first 9 bytes are flags which i dont need in my string stream, next 2 bytes are some data i need as string, let's call them "name1", next 2 bytes are another name, lest call it "name2", then comes 4 bytes which are some uint32 number(but writen as 4 uint8 bytes), lets call it just "number". Now i need to pass these data to stringstream but:

- name1 and number2 need to be written as bytes (byte 0x52 -> char[2]={"5","2"})
- number needs to be casted to uint32
- all variables need to be seperated by semicolons in final stringstream

so if im getting a vector like this one:

---some 9 bytes---, 0x05, 0x00, 0x01,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x08,0x0E, ---some other data---

i need stringstream to be like this:

"0500;0100;2062;"

i have managed to figure out how to cast number to uint32:

```
uint8_t tab[4];
for(int i=4; i!=0; --i)
{
    tab[4-i]=data[i+14];
}
uint32_t* var = (uint32_t*)tab;
```

is there some better way to do this?

EDIT:

How can i pass uint8 values to string as characters?

example:

byte ouput: 0x05

string output: 05

can i put string to stringstream using "<<" operator or is it not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

if you have a string, just loop on the string and output the characters to your stringstream

```
std::string name = "name1";
std::stringstream ss;
for(auto c : name)
  ss << std::static_cast<int>(c);
ss << ";";
```

As a side note:

```
uint32_t* var = (uint32_t*)tab;
```

is totally useless, you don't need a pointer.

Comment: ok i get what u mean, but i need to fill string with uint8 characters from data vector, how can i fill string with these characters, so that for 0x05 and 0x00 in data vector will look in string like this: "0500"
i need only these two bytes. then i need to cast it

Comment: your question is not really clear. Please clarify and don't write in sms-like english. If you need to fill a string you can always `append` your characters to the string you need.

Comment: Added an edit with claryfication, hope it makes my problem clear.

Answer (score -1):

i'm not sure this will solve your problem, but i would take a different approach.

i would use a struct to describe the underlying protocol and then continue with that. example:

```
struct dx{
  uint8 _junk0[9];
  char  name1[2];
  char  name2[2];
  uint32 num;
} __attribute__((packed));

uint8 *input;
dx* struct=(dx*)input;
printf("%d",dx->num);
```

Comment: this is so `C`, the `C++` way would be to override operator `<<` Also not using `printf` but `cout`

Comment: A much bigger problem is that this violates strict aliasing.

Comment: @Voo: thank you for noting that, i've read about it - and yes it does that ;)